# How to report custom message in protractor report?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using protractor tool with Jasmine framework to write automation scripts.

Got "Wait timed out after 3000ms" error when an element was not appearing in the page. This message looks so generic. So, I want to report a custom message such as: "The element was not showed up for 5 seconds after the page loading. Hence, terminating the execution of the script.".

Can any anyone help me to add a custom message to the reporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser.wait function allow you to pass an additional parameter for custom log messages, see [api documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait)

```
browser.wait(element, 5 * 1000, 'The element was not showed up for 5 seconds after the page loading. Hence, terminating the execution of the script.');
```